# Doctrine Criteria: determine if processed value is in collection's element array-like-field

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine-orm

I need to define Doctrine `Criteria` and filter `ArrayCollection` in the way that every collection's element could be defined with specific field's value as simple scalar or array of scalars (integers). Criteria should define accepted field's value (scalar) and it should be matched if scalar=scalar OR if scalar is in array of scalars.

I have collection of scenarios, like:

```
$scenarios = new ArrayCollection([
    ['code' => 1],
    ['code' => [2, 3]]
]);
```

And `Criteria` like:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->where($criteria->expr()->contains('code', 1));
$matching = $scenarios->matching($criteria);
```

But it's not working for arrays since `Comparison::CONTAINS` only checks if value is part of a field with `strpos`. `Comparison::IN` works the other way I need - it checks if collection element field's value is in array specified in criteria's expression.

Is it possible to achieve what I need? Do I need to create custom class which implements `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr\Expression`? How to do it?

PS. Yes, I know I could normalize collection and make everywhere arrays, but it only simplifies handling of a condition. It does not solve the problem since Doctrine's built-in comparisions does not support matching arrays in "my way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is new comparison `MEMBER_OF` in [`master branch`](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/issues/81#issuecomment-223121256) which should be released soon according to [Guilherme Blanco's comment](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/issues/81#issuecomment-223121256). It works exactly as needed, so just use `dev-master` or wait for `v1.4`.